# Can't dismiss invites from shared Google calendars in Calendar.app

Tags: calendar, ical, google-calendar

At work we use Google Apps for Work. The calendar feature in Google Apps for Work allows you to add other colleagues' calendars to your own so that you can see their schedules. When I import my work account into Calendar.app, I see each of my colleagues' calendars as an option that I can display or hide.

The problem I'm having is that meeting invitations sent to my colleagues are getting sent to me, and I have no way of dismissing them from my calendar.app queue without either declining or accepting the meeting on behalf of my colleague, which I do not want to do. How can I prevent invites sent to these calendars from showing up in my queue?

Comment: Did you ever solve this I have the exact same problem? Being bugging me for ages!